# Is it possible to serialize only specific classes/functions in pickle / dill python?

Tags: python-2.7, pickle, joblib, dill

I have an app that want to serialize only classes/functions which are:
   no Python primitive data type
   no Numpy data type
   no pandas data type.

So, is it possible to filter object to be saved in dill ?
(filter by loop on the type)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is not a complete solution (i.e. you'd probably want to include more of the modules with `pandas` data types, `numpy` data types… and also you might want to be more selective for the built-in types by filtering by `type` instead of module)… I think it sort of gets you what you want.

```
>>> import dill
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas
>>> 
>>> target = numpy.array([1,2,3])
>>> dill.dumps(target) if not dill.source.getmodule(type(target)) in [numpy, pandas.core.series, dill.source.getmodule(int)] else None
>>> 
>>> target = [1,2,3]             
>>> dill.dumps(target) if not dill.source.getmodule(type(target)) in [numpy, pandas.core.series, dill.source.getmodule(int)] else None
>>> 
>>> target = lambda x:x   
>>> dill.dumps(target) if not dill.source.getmodule(type(target)) in [numpy, pandas.core.series, dill.source.getmodule(int)] else None
>>> 
>>> class Foo(object): 
...   pass
... 
>>> target = Foo()     
>>> dill.dumps(target) if not dill.source.getmodule(type(target)) in [numpy, pandas.core.series, dill.source.getmodule(int)] else None
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\x03Fooq\x05h\x01U\nObjectTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\r__slotnames__q\x0b]q\x0cU\n__module__q\rU\x08__main__q\x0eU\x07__doc__q\x0fNutq\x10Rq\x11)\x81q\x12}q\x13b.'
>>>
```

However, if you are asking if `dill` has such a filtering method, then the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks, Just need to create a big list of all primitives types, numpy, and pandas ones.

It can be used as regression testing, to throw in dill a list of complex/no standard class and see which ones passed / failed.

This list can be maintained by community (make it easier to detect which class is serialized / not serialized).

Comment: @Tensor: `dill` includes a list of python objects from the standard library that is can and can't serialize.  If you do some variant of `dill.load_types()` and then look at the types in `dill.types` you'll see what `dill` can (and, depending on the kwds used in `load_types`, can't serialize).  This is not a complete list.  There's even a more comprehensive listing that is maintained in `dill._objects`, and that is still primarily the standard library objects.  I would be interested in seeing what you come up with, and please feel free to submit a PR.